# Explicit show that map is continous in the topological sense

Tags: general-topology

I am studying physics and I'm trying to get a better understanding of topology. A map $A:X\rightarrow Y$ between two topological spaces $(X,\tau_x), (Y,\tau_y)$ is called continuous, if the preimage of every open set in $Y$ is also a open set in $X$. I now want to figure out, how to explicitly show for a given Map $A$ if it is continous. Let's consider the topological spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. How can I for example explicitly show, that
\begin{align}
A: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
A(x,y) = x+y
\end{align}
is continous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show this for any open interval $(a,b)$ as this is a base for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$. Let $a<b$ and consider
$$
S:=A^{-1}((a,b)) = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:a<x+y<b\}.
$$
This region is bounded by (but does not include) the lines $x=b-a$ and $y=x$ in $\mathbb R^2$. So if $(x,y)\in S$ then there exist $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$ such that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(y-(b-a))^2}&=|y-(b-a)|=\varepsilon_1\\
\sqrt{(x-y)^2}&=|x-y|=\varepsilon_2.
\end{align}
Let $\varepsilon=\min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}$, then the open ball with center $(x,y)$ and radius $\varepsilon$ is contained in $S$, so that $S$ is open. It follows that $A$ is continuous.